# Internal login with mysql membership provider on MVC 3

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, membership-provider

I have a MVC3 project with mysql membership provider and entity framework. It's there a way to perform a user login from code? I mean... a method that allow me to login with any user of my site **only with the user name** from code?